# Rails Test errors, while learning rails tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently learning Rails Tutorial. I have error messages after rails test, TDD. There are more messages, but first of all i want to debug these. Even though rails test is not working well, application itself is working without problem as of now.

I took a look this sample codes.
https://github.com/yasslab/sample_apps

## Error messages

```
 11) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_about:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_about_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00000006f89228>
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_home:NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_home_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00000006f964a0>
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:7:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>' 13) Error:
StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_contact:NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_contact_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x0000000623d600>
    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>' 14) Error:StaticPagesControllerTest#test_should_get_help:NameError: undefined local variable or method `static_pages_help_url' for #<StaticPagesControllerTest:0x00000006f9d6d8>    test/controllers/static_pages_controller_test.rb:13:in `block in <class:StaticPagesControllerTest>'
```

## static_pages_controller.rb

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
  end

  def help
  end

  def about
  end

  def contact
  end
end
```

## static_pages_controller_test.rb

```
class StaticPagesControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase


  test "should get home" do
    get static_pages_home_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get help" do
    get static_pages_help_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Help | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end

  test "should get about" do
    get static_pages_about_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "About | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"

  end


  test "should get contact" do
    get static_pages_contact_url
    assert_response :success
    assert_select "title", "Contact | Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
  end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'

  root 'static_pages#home'
  get  '/help',    to: 'static_pages#help'
  get  '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
  get  '/contact', to: 'static_pages#contact'
  get  '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  post '/signup', to: 'users#create'

  get '/login', to: 'sessions#new'
  post '/login', to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout', to: 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :users
end
```

I want to make these errors into assertions.
Could you kindly help me?

Comment: What do your routes look like?

Comment: I have added the codes of routes.rb. Please take a look.

Comment: Try adding this to the top of your test file: `require test_helper`. And change your test file to inherit from: `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` instead of `ActionController::TestCase`.

Comment: thanks. I could make these assertions.